# Replace a cell's value in pandas to a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, string, tuples

This might be a simple question but I tried searching for the answer and I can't seem to find it.
I have a pandas dataframe and I want to change the value of some cells to a tuple.

So if I have this:

```
 Col0    Col1     Col2
   3      a        6
   7      b        8
```

I would like to change all the "a" values to a tuple:

```
Col0      Col1     Col2
3         (4,5)      6
7          b         8
```

I tried doing this:

```
df.loc[df["Col1"] == "a"] = (4,5,)
```

but it obviously didn't work. I don't know how I can do this.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try boolean indexing with `loc` to update the values in the cells in `Col1` which contains `a`:

```
m = df['Col1'].eq('a')
df.loc[m, 'Col1'] = pd.Series([(4, 5)]*m.sum(), index=m[m].index)
```

Alternatively you can try **[`.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html)** with `fill_value` parameter set to tuple `(4, 5)`:

```
m = df['Col1'].eq('a')
df['Col1'] = df.loc[~m, 'Col1'].reindex(m.index, fill_value=(4, 5))
```

---

```
   Col0    Col1  Col2
0     3  (4, 5)     6
1     7       b     8
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Col0': [3,7], 'Col1': ['a', 'b'], 'Col2': [6, 8]})
df.set_value(0, 'Col1', (4, 5))
```

Or, if you don't know where 'a' is (and in case we have more than one 'a0 per column, you can do that with a loop:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Col0': [3,7], 'Col1': ['a', 'b'], 'Col2': [6, 8]})
# find the position of a in 'Col1'
where_a = np.where(df['Col1'] == 'a')[0]

# replace a with tuple (4, 5)
for x in where_a:
    df.set_value(x, 'Col1', (4, 5))

   Col0    Col1  Col2
0     3  (4, 5)     6
1     7       b     8
```